# setup table size and font size in outlook email

Tags: php, css, outlook

I have html table which I am using it as body of email, Problem is that Table font size what I have set in CSS doesn't reflect the same in outlook email.

Any Idea how to do this? Have font size set to table?

Using php

Comment: You used css like: <table  style="font-size:14px"></table> or used css  file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply inline CSS only.

```
<table style="font-size: ....">
```

if that doesn't work - not sure at the moment whether font-size inherits through a table's elements - set the `font-size` to the `td` element:

```
<td style="font-size: ....">
```